# What is the proper declaration in HTML head?

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=width-divice, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" href="images/icon/icon.png">
  <title>T@O</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
   </head>
  </html>
```

I ask if there is a lacking code that need to put

Comment: it really depends. Your head section is fine, but it can have lots of things depending on project, libraries and frameworks you use

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. This looks like a HTML5 site, english language, utf-8 encoding. "divice" should probably be "device". A favicon will be stored in images/icon/ and a stylesheet in style/. If all that's correct, it looks like you're ready to go. If you want any javascript loaded you'd best put script tags here, too.

Comment: Does anyone dare to post an answer consisting of "Not really."? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this meta tags for SEO if you want

```
<meta name="keywords" content="wood, furniture, garden, gardentable, etc">
<meta name="description" content="Official dealer of wooden garden furniture.">
```

This meta tags tells search engines not to index the page and prevent them from following the links. If you happen to be using two contradictory terms (e.g. noindex and index), Google will choose the most restrictive option.

```
<meta name=”robots” content=”noindex, nofollow” />
```

Why is this tag useful for SEO? First of all it’s a simple way to prevent the indexation of duplicate content, for example the print version of a page. It might also be useful for incomplete pages or pages with confidential information.

Also i sometimes use

```
<meta name="author" content="John Smith">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your viewport declaration - it needs to be "device-width". Other than that, your `head` declaration includes all the necessary parts and looks valid to me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" href="images/icon/icon.png">
  <title>T@O</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
</head>
</html>
```